# Checking that a price value in a string is in the correct format

Tags: parsing, haskell

I use n <- getLine to get from user price. How can I check is value correct ? (Price can have '.' and digits and must be greater than 0) ?

---

It doesn't work:

```
isFloat = do
    n <- getLine
    let val = case reads n of
                ((v,_):_) -> True
                _ -> False
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading a string and testing if it is a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084013/reading-a-string-and-testing-if-it-is-a-number)

Answer (score 4):

**If The Input Is Always Valid Or Exceptions Are OK**

If you have users entering decimal numbers in the form of "123.456" then this can simply be converted to a Float or Double using `read`:

```
n <- getLine
let val = read n
```

Or in one line (having imported `Control.Monad`):

```
n <- liftM read getLine
```

**To Catch Erroneous Input**

The above code fails with an exception if the users enter invalid entries.  If that's a problem then use reads and `listToMaybe` (from `Data.Maybe`):

```
n <- liftM (fmap fst . listToMaybe . reads) getLine
```

If that code looks complex then don't sweat it - the below is the same operation but doing all the work with explicit case statements:

```
n <- getLine
let val = case reads n of
            ((v,_):_) -> Just v
            _ -> Nothing
```

Notice we pattern match to get the first element of the tuple in the head of the list, The head of the list being `(v,_)` and the first element is `v`.  The underscore (`_`) just means "ignore the value in this spot".

**If Floating Point Isn't Acceptable**

Floating values are well known to be approximate, and not suitable for real world financial computations (but perhaps homework, depending on your professor).  In this case you'd want to read the values into a `Rational` (from `Data.Ratio`).

```
n <- liftM maybeRational getLine
...
  where
  maybeRational :: String -> Maybe Rational
  maybeRational str =
      let (a,b) = break (=='.') str
      in liftM2 (%) (readMaybe a) (readMaybe $ drop 1 b)
  readMaybe = fmap fst . listToMaybe . reads
```

Comment: hmm I wouldn't advice storing prices into `Double` variables.

Comment: Yeah, prices should be Integers unless you want to deal with rounding errors.

Comment: Note that `(v,_):_)` pattern would accept inputs with trailing garbage, like "23.99foobar". Obviously, one needs to match the second element of the pair against `[]` to avoid this confusing behavior.

Comment: Good answer. Or perhaps consider `Data.Fixed` for fixed-precision.

Comment: But I would like to have function which returns true is value is float or false if not.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the parsing advice provided by TomMD, consider using the appropriate monad for error reporting. It allows you to conveniently chain computations which can fail, avoiding explicit error checking on every step.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Monad.Error

parsePrice :: MonadError String m => String -> m Double
parsePrice s = do
    x <- case reads s of
        [(x, "")] -> return x
        _         -> throwError "Not a valid real number."
    when (x <= 0) $ throwError "Price must be positive."
    return x

main = do
    n <- getLine
    case parsePrice n of
        Left err -> putStrLn err
        Right x  -> putStrLn $ "Price is " ++ show x
```

Comment: But I would like to have function which returns true is value is float or false if not.